# Teradata 14: Timestamp with timezone issue

Tags: teradata

I want to load `data.txt` using `MLOAd`

data.txt

```
1,20030101020000.000000,20030101020000.000000 -08:00
```

Table def:

```
create table  test
( sno varchar(3),
  ts_name TIMESTAMP(6) ,
  ts_zonename TIMESTAMP(6) WITH TIME ZONE
);
```

Mload insert :

```
insert into test (sno,ts_name,ts_zonename) 
   values (:in_sno,
           CAST(:in_ts_name AS TIMESTAMP(     6)  FORMAT 'YYYYMMDDHHMISSDS(     6)'),
           CAST(:in_ts_zonename   AS TIMESTAMP(     6)  FORMAT  'YYYYMMDDHHMISSDS(     6)')
                     );
```

mload success .

When i Query

```
SEL EXTRACT(TIMEZONE_HOUR FROM ts_zonename) 
        FROM test;
```

through BTEQ

it returns 0

Shouldn't it return -8 ?

I am on Teradata 14

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You CASTed to a TIMESTAMP which dropped the time zone, check the actual data inserted into ts_zonename.

You need to cast to a TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE:

```
CAST(:in_ts_zonename   AS TIMESTAMP(     6) WITH TIME ZONE  FORMAT  'YYYYMMDDHHMISSDS(F)Z')
```

And if there's an space before the time zone you need to change the FORMAT to `'YYYYMMDDHHMISSDS(F)BZ'` or switch to Oracle's `TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ` in TD14, which is a bit more flexible regarding missing/additional blanks:

```
TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ(ts_zonename,  'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS.FF6TZH:TZM')
```

Comment: Thanks Doneth , CAST(:in_ts_zonename AS TIMESTAMP(     6)  WITH TIME ZONE FORMAT  'YYYYMMDDHHMISSDS(     6)Z') .. This also worked for me when i removed space before -8:00